# SCORM 2004 - 3rd Edition

Tags: scorm2004

I've created a some pages into HTML/CSS/Javascript having assessment as well. but now need to implement Scorm 2004 3rd into my package. So can anyone suggest or guide me the process to implement? or can anyone provide me sample with scorm complaint?

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://github.com//cybercussion/SCOBot/wiki.  Tons of info, downloadable examples.

What you are asking is a massive subject.  At the top of it all is -
Are you progressing one page at a time on the LMS?
Or are you progressing all pages within your assessment (SCO)?

This greatly changes your outcome and what you'll need to do.

There is an example of a one page progression on that wiki.  Fail that, your're building out your own navigation and will need to use AJAX to load your pages.